# Incorrect div align of twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to append data to div using json request.
What i am trying to do is just simple fetch json request and then create div (`<div class="col-md-4">My div box</div>`) and append to previously created div.

Now initially everything is right and working but after some time their alignment was wrong. It shows me something like below screenshot.

[image]

But it should be like this as early this was okay.

**Previous screen shot**

[image]

I guess this is due to HTML cache or may be dynamically div appending by JavaScript.

Comment: Please, post your completed code instead of image. Nobody can solve your problem by image.

Comment: More importantly, what happened when Andy's mum's toy came?

Comment: Can you gave us the code thank you.

Comment: Please refer to browser element section in 1 screenshot.These div is generated by javascript. actually some time it work and sometime it will not.

Answer (score 0):

Make the `col-md-4` class the same height, this will float the divs properly

Answer (score -1):

In the first screen shot the three column height are different that why it broken , so it's better you just set an fixed height for the column then it should work.
set height for the class 'feed-box'. 
i hope this will do it for you.